# Java/JPA/Sping - Spring don't send correct model properties names to the front/end. Some cache is happening between the back and the front

Tags: java, spring, jpa, caching

I've an issue with some kind of cache happening between the back/end and the front/end.
Spring don't send correct model properties names to the front/end.

My model looks like :

```
public Content(
        int id, 
        Set<Permission> permission, 
        Set<Os> os, 
        Set<Langage> langages, 
        Set<Framework> frameworks, 
        Set<Library> libraries, 
        String content
        ) {
            super();
            this.id= id;
            this.permission = permission;
            this.os= os;
            this.langages= langages;
            this.frameworks= frameworks;
            this.libraries= libraries;
            this.content= content;
}
```

But when I do a Get on my browser :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/doc/content/")
public ResponseEntity<List<Content>> getDoc() {
    List<Content> content = contentDao.findAll();
    System.out.println(content);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(content);
}
```

1. My object structure in front ain't right. The data is correct and comes from the db, but the properties names are all wrong.

   > ```
   > blabla: 5,
   > contentblabla: "uilui;",
   > framework: [{"id": 38, "name": "Java"}],
   > langage: [],
   > library: [{"id": 23, "name": "GSAP"}],
   > osblabla: [{id: 24, name: "Windows"}],
   > permiblabla: []
   > ```
2. My object structure in back/end is correct (I check it from "System.out.println(content);")

As I've been playing around, I can guess it's some kind of cache since previous names I gave to this model.

Now my issue is that I've no idea how to get rid of that cache and I'd like to be able to change my models properties names.
I tried to clean the project, to change the path, clear the browser cache, etc

Does anyone knows what is the problem ?

The repo is [here](https://github.com/j-42/jazapp/tree/main/documentation/src/main/java/com/jm) if you need more detail.

Thank you !

Comment: The DocContent class seems to be correct, is there a difference with the Content class you are mentioning in this example? If so, post it please.

Comment: Yes if you checked the code, you might have seen Content, Content2 and DocContent classes. The original is DocContent, I used the others to test the behavior in fornt/end. When you check the properties, you can see for exemple that in the model you have `this.content= content;`, but in the object the front gets, the properties is `contentblabla` instead of `content`. That comes from playing around testing but now I can't see any logic as I removed all the test code.

Comment: I can't seem to find Content or Content2. Are you sure you pushed your changes to the repo? Also, have you tried using @JsonProperty("Value") to manually specify the field name that'll be used in the object's serialization? If so, does the 'contentblabla' name gets overriden?

Comment: Yes I removed Content or Content2 now. When I use `@JsonProperty("Value")`, I get the correct properties in my object in front, but I also get the old properties for some reason. So I get my object where each property is doubled, one with the correct labels, one with an old label which doesn't exist in the code anymore.